# XPATH filter tag-less children

Tags: xpath

Is there any way to specify that I want to select only tag-less child elements (in the following example - "text")?

```
<div>
   <p>...</p>
   "text"
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

The `text()` function matches text nodes. Example: `//div/text()` — matches all text children within all `div` elements.

Comment: `text()` is not a function, strictly speaking. It's a *node test*, just like the `div` in `//div` is a node test. The parentheses are merely to make a difference to `//text`.

Comment: Also note that with the given input sample, `//div/text()` does select two such text nodes, one before the `p` element, this one only contains white space, the second one after the `p` element. So you might want `//div/text()[normalize-space()]` to exclude any pure white space text nodes.

Answer (score 1):

**Use**:

```
/*/text()[normalize-space()]
```

This selects all text nodes that are children of the top element of the document and that do not consist only of white-space characters.

**In the concrete example this will select only the text node with string value**:

```
'
       "text"
    '
```

The XPath expressions:

```
/*/text()
```

or

```
/div/text()
```

both select *two* text nodes, the first of which contains only white-space and the second is the same text node as above:

```
'
       "text"
    '
```

Answer (score 0):

> select only tag-less child elements

To me this sounds like selecting all *elements* that don't have other elements as children. But then again, "text" in your example is **not** an element, but a text node, so I'm not really sure what do you want to select... 
Anyway, here is a solution for selecting such *elements*.

```
//*[not(*)]
```

Selects all elements that don't have an element as a child. Replace the first * with an element name if you only want to select certain elements that don't have child elements. Also note that using `//` is generally slow since it runs through the whole document. Consider using more specific path when possible (like `/div/*[not(*)]` in this case).